# My css is not working in magento 2

Tags: css, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I had installed `Magento 2.0.2` and also override the templates I am stuck on a point that where do i write my css for my own styling. How do i change the css of existing template.

i have done these steps

create `_theme.less`

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/source/_theme.less
```

and deploy the content by using

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

also change the Front-end development workflow into client side less compilation and i found the `styles.css` file included at backend which source was

```
pub/media/styles.css
```

if i make changes in `styles.css` then it will apply on frontend and backend both.

now i want to write my own css to apply my own created theme how can i do that?

thanks alot!

Comment: can you share your `_theme.less`

Comment: .page-header{
    background-color: #000;
}

Comment: sir i am stuck on it. help me please. :(

Comment: add the file path too.

Comment: @QaisarSatti kindly check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

add your custom theme and try to make changes there.

```
<head>
<css src="css/style.css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this steps.

1. Create css file under this directory.
   **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/customcss.css**
2. Create **default_head_blocks.xml** file if not exist at this path
   **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

Put below code in **default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <css src="css/customcss.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your tree looks like this:

-app
--design
---frontend
----VendorName
-----VendorTheme
------Magento-Theme
-------layout
--------default.xml
--------default_head_blocks.xml
------media
-------preview.png
------web
-------css
--------yourcss.css
------registration.php
------theme.xml